# getting Null value from Persistent object

Tags: blackberry, hashtable, persistent-storage

I am trying to store the registration state of the user in my app. i have used Persistent store. But i am not getting the data bak from the store. I have written the below code:

```java
package com.saiservices.util;

import java.util.Enumeration;

import com.saiservices.ui.Logger;


import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentObject;
import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentStore;
import net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable;

public class SaiPersistentStore implements Persistable{

    private SaiHashTable mElements = null;
    static SaiPersistentStore instance;
    private static final long KEY = xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    private PersistentObject persistentObject = null;


    /**
     * Gets the single instance of DataBase.
     * 
     * @return single instance of DataBase
     */
    public static SaiPersistentStore getInstance() {
        try {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new SaiPersistentStore();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            instance = null;
        }
        return instance;
    }


    private SaiPersistentStore()
    {
         Logger.out("PersistentStoreInfo", "inside constructor  ");
        persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);
         synchronized (persistentObject) 
           { 
               if (persistentObject.getContents() == null) 
               { 
                   persistentObject.setContents(new SaiHashTable()); 
                   persistentObject.commit(); 
               }  
           }

         mElements = (SaiHashTable)persistentObject.getContents();
         if (mElements == null){
             Logger.out("PersistentStoreInfo", "************"+(mElements == null));
             mElements = new SaiHashTable();
         }
    }


    public String getElement(String key)
    {
        Logger.out("PersistentStoreInfo", "getElement :"+key);
        Logger.out("PersistentStoreInfo", "getElement value   :"+mElements.get(key));

        return (String) mElements.get(key);
    }

    public void setElement(String key, String value)
    {
        Logger.out("PersistentStoreInfo", "setElement11111 :"+key + "   "+value);
        mElements.put(key, value);
        persistentObject.setContents(mElements);
        Logger.out("PersistentStoreInfo", "setElement22222 :"+key+"   "+value);
        persistentObject.commit(); 
    }

    public Enumeration getAllKeys() 
    {
        return mElements.keys();
    }

}
```

And here is the hashtable code:

```java
package com.saiservices.util;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable;

public class SaiHashTable extends Hashtable implements Persistable{

    public SaiHashTable(){
        super();
    }
    public SaiHashTable(int initialCepacity){
        super(initialCepacity);
    }

}
```

Now i am setting the element like this:

```java
SaiPersistentStore.getInstance().setElement("Registration","on");
```

But when i am trying to get the element in theis way, gettting null value:

```java
 SaiPersistentStore.getInstance().getElement("Register")
```

Where i am doing wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following line from `setElement()` method:

```
    persistentObject.setContents(mElements);
```

by doing this, you are overwriting the contents of the persitent object, which were earlier a SaiHashTable object. So next time you try to cast the contents of the persistent object, you get an exception which you catch and then reset the instance.

Also you should try to get the same value you have set:

`SaiPersistentStore.getInstance().getElement("Registration")`

Comment: I have commented. But still i am getting value as null.

Comment: Use the same key for getting value "Registration" and not "Register". I have changed the answer.

Comment: Oh shit!! Now i am getting. What a mistake after writing so much code. Thanks.

Comment: The first suggestion (remove call to `setContents()`) isn't actually the problem, right?  It was that he was using different key names (your second suggestion)?  I think calling `setContents()` is unnecessary in his case, but I don't think it hurts anything.  `mElements` is in fact the original `new SaiHashTable()` instance that he first passed to `setContents()`, so it should have no effect.

Comment: Yes the issue mainly is misspelling of the key value. And persistentObject.setContents(mElements); this is required in this case. But what i observed is, in the getElement() method, i need to check the existence of the key in the hashtable. If it is not there, return value need to be change. Very soon, i need to be keep it in my forum. So that some other dev can use it.

Comment: @Nate yes you are right, I confused the mElements with something else.

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee it is generally a good idea to never call `setContents()` more than once in the lifetime of the persistent object as it may lead to hard to debug problems. For example, if your app is using this persistent object in different processes together - say a background and another foreground app, both will initially have the same object mElements. If you replace the contents in one of the processes with another object, the other process will not know about it and still refer to and use the older mElements object.